# How do I patch a port in macports?

Tags: python, selenium, macports

I'm totally new to Mac OS X (running Lion), and I'm trying to use macports to run python2.7 and selenium. I have the ports installed, but the selenium port is very out of date (2.0rc3, whereas 2.11 is current). A patch exists to update the selenium port to v2.9 but I have no idea what to do with it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The process for upgrading a port file yourself is described [here](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/Upgrade).  You should also check the issue tracker and, if someone has not already done so, [open an issue](https://trac.macports.org/newticket) requesting that the port be upgraded.  If you can supply a patch, chances are it will be applied quickly for everyone to use.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find official information on macports website, but this is how I do it.

First you need to download the patch. It should be attached to the bug report you mention. Then you need to find the the portfile that needs patching. You can do that with:

```
port file PORTNAME
```

Finally, you need to apply the patch. For that can do:

```
sudo patch PATH/TO/PORTNAME PATCH-YOU-DOWNLOADED.diff
```